# How to make any service running on docker host available to its containers?

Tags: docker, containers, docker-machine

I am trying to find a solution to make a process/service running on host available inside a container. Example a host is running Apache2 service which has 4 containers running. Just the way using VOLUMNES we can link the host's directory to container, is there any way to fork a reference of the Apache2 service from host to container?

Answer (score 1):

You ask in general terms which makes this hard to answer, since different services communicate with their clients in different ways.

But let's take a service that communicates over http like Apache. You have that running on the host at port 8080. Then you can add the host with the option `--addhost=host.docker.internal:host-gateway` on the `docker run` command and you'll then be able to reach the host at `host.docker.internal` from inside the container.

As an example, you can use a curl image and reach the Apache server from inside the container like this

```
docker run --rm --add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway curlimages/curl http://host.docker.internal:8080/
```

Note the URL at the end (`http://host.docker.internal:8080/`) which will hit port 8080 on the host.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Docker official doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#add-host):

```bash
echo "hello from host!" > ./hello
python3 -m http.server 8000
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 (http://0.0.0.0:8000/) ...
docker run \
  --add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway \
  curlimages/curl -s host.docker.internal:8000/hello
hello from host!
```